# Can I run a script using sudo? Like this: sudo script.sh

Tags: bash, sudo

If I write a shell script that has commands that require superuser privileges to execute, will that script run if I used `sudo` while executing the script? As in:

```
sudo script.sh
```

Comment: Did you try something? You could easily find the answer to your question just trying to write a script with a command that requires root privileges and running it with sudo.

Comment: You will need to prefix the script name with `./` , like this: `sudo ./script.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all the commands in your script will run as `root`. [See also](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479055/shell-script-use-sudo-inside-it-vs-run-it-with-sudo).

But keep in mind that running your whole script with `sudo` will also affect some environment variables like `$USER`, which will be `root` instead of your normal users name, but depending on the `sudo` configuration it will not affect others, e.g. `$HOME`. [See also](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91384/how-is-sudo-set-to-not-change-home-in-ubuntu-and-how-to-disable-this-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will.
Before that check the permissions if the script has the x (executable) permissions as well. Without it it won't run at all.

You can check that by listing the files in that directory with ls -la
If there is no **x** in the permissions try to add it but be careful to not make it executable for all (e.x. 777)